# C# - Double spaces in DB field causing unwanted newlines when writing to a text file

Tags: c#, sql

*Let me preface this by saying I have never really coded in C# (I'm a Python programmer) and I coded in C++ back in college a little bit*

I have an SSIS package that has several C# script components (found the script online somewhere) that essentially reads data from a database and writes it to a text file. When I started data validation I noticed my file had about 3500 more rows in it than the database table itself. After writing a python script to compare the data, I realized that we have a database field called "REMARKS" that has been appended to several times. Whenever it is appended it apparently causes a double space (hitting space bar twice).

When the script encounters this double white space issue it will write to a new line. I do NOT want it to do this. I need all those remarks to stay in its original field. Please see my script below.

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        try
        {
            //Declare Variables
            string FileNamePart = Dts.Variables["$Project::pvarWorkorderFlatFileNamePart"].Value.ToString();
            string DestinationFolder = Dts.Variables["$Project::pvarDestinationFolder"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["$Project::pvarWorkorderTableName"].Value.ToString();
            string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["$Project::pvarFileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
            string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["$Project::pvarFileExtension"].Value.ToString();

            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DB_CNXN"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

            //Read data from table or view to data table
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
            //myADONETConnection.Open();
            DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
            d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            myADONETConnection.Close();

            string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileNamePart + "_" + date + FileExtension;

            StreamWriter sw = null;
            sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

            // Write the Header Row to File
            int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
            for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
            {
                sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            // Write All Rows to the File
            foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
            {
                for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                    }
                    if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["$Project::pvarLogFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

}

So the database table row might look something like this:

```
tip|date      |remarks                                                     |completed|device_id
n  |2018-01-03|1st att 9/7/17  2nd att 9/12/17  3rd att 11/7/17 need code  |Y        |123
```

(Notice double spaces in remarks field between each of those entries including after the last one)
When the script runs and outputs to the file this is what it would look like (file is pipe (|) delimitted):

```
Line 1:n|2018-01-03|
Line 2:1st att 9/7/17
Line 3:2nd att 9/12/17
Line 4:3rd att 11/7/17 need code
Line 5:
Line 6:|Y|1234
```

I just need the script to take the rows as-is and keep everything on one line like this:

```
Line 1:n|2018-01-03|1st att 9/7/17  2nd att 9/12/17  3rd att 11/7/17 need code  |Y|1234
```

I am pulling the data from a SQL database and if there are no double spaces in the remarks field, then the script functions as intended.

If someone could PLEASE help I would be forever grateful! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure these are really space chars (ASCII 20) in the database?

Comment: I’m honestly not sure. Is there a simple way to check this?

Comment: @Klau Gutter - It looks like they weren't double spaces because I tried the below answer and it did not work.

Comment: You could use the debugger to have a look at dr[ir]

Comment: Guessing that these are in fact '\n' and/or '\r', try to replace these chars by ' '.

Comment: Ok yep I got it figured out now. It wasn't double spaces it was the CRLF. I had to use .Replace("\r\n","_") and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistaken that it was double spaces, as it actually was CRLF (\r\n) that was in the database. So taking what @Ali Maleki provided above, I used this to solve my issue:

```
sw.Write((dr[ir].ToString()).Replace("\r\n","_"));
```

Thanks for your guys' help!

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in your code : `sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());`

Replace with : `sw.Write((dr[ir].ToString()).Replace(' ', '_'));`

Result :

```
Line 1:n|2018-01-03|1st_att_9/7/17__2nd_att_9/12/17__3rd_att_11/7/17_need code__|Y|1234
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work unfortunately. I guess maybe @Klaus Gutter had a point in asking "are you sureu these are really space chars (ASCII 20) in the database?" Because it looks like that is not the case. Do you know how I can check this or what I would do to solve this issue?

Comment: I edited your answer to show what I did to solve the issue. Thanks again!